# how to solve element overlap problem in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a row of 3 children and I am sending one of them from another page. I want it to be side by side with the text, but it stays above the text. How can I fix this problem?

```html
Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            textComponent ?? Container(),
                            Flexible(
                              fit: FlexFit.loose,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 140,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      state.value == initialValue
                                          ? initialValueLabel ?? ""
                                          : valueLabel ?? "",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)
                          ],
                        ),
```

[image]

```
textComponent: girisHesapTipi != ""
                      ? ClipOval(
                          child: Container(
                          //todo renk dinamik değişecek
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                          child: Text(
                            girisHesapTipi,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ))
                      : null,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Row(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
 children: [
    textComponent ?? Container(),
    const SizedBox(width: 10),
    Flexible(
      Text(
        state.value == initialValue
         ? initialValueLabel ?? ""
         : valueLabel ?? "",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
       overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
    Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
  ]
)
```

where `textComponent` is:

```
girisHesapTipi.isNotEmpty
  ? Container(
      //todo renk dinamik değişecek
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Colors.grey,
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      child: Align(
       alignment: Alignment.center,
       child: Text(
        girisHesapTipi,
        style: TextStyle(
         color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
   : null,
```

Comment: I tried before, it doesn't work

Comment: What type of widget is `textComponent`? Does it have a fixed `height` and `width`?

Comment: Maybe ClipOval is giving some sort of problem, try the version of `textComponent` I just added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```html
 textComponent: detayTemp?.cikisValue?[0]  != null
                      ? Row(
                        children: [
                          ClipOval(
                          child: Container(
                            //todo renk dinamik değişecek
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                            child: Text(
                              detayTemp?.cikisValue?[0] ?? "",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          )),
                          SizedBox(width: 5,)
                        ],
                      )
                      : null,
```